# print statement inside of input returns with a "none"

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I am working on a little program and I want to use:

```
ans = int(input(print(multi,'x',num,'=')))
```

This works well except for the fact that after it prints the print statement it says none. like:

```
49 x 7 =
None
```

How would on remove the "none" if possible? Also I did search this problem but nothing was about returning a none inside of an input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`input`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#input) takes a `prompt` string as its argument, which it will print automatically, but `print` returns `None`; it is this that gets printed by `input`. Your code is equivalent to:

```
prompt = print(...) # prompt == None
ans = int(input(prompt))
```

Instead, use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to build the prompt and pass it straight to `input`:

```
ans = int(input('{0}x{1}='.format(multi, num)))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Differently going in the memory bank.