# None word is prompting while taking input by passing print statement in python

Tags: python

```
def prompt(n):
    value= int(input(print("Please enter integer #", n, ": ",end='')))
    return value
```

in python giving result as (if n=1)

```
>>>Please enter integer # 1 : None
```

Why None word is coming while executing above function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [print statement inside of input returns with a "none"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350509/print-statement-inside-of-input-returns-with-a-none)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the print statement.

`print` is just a function and by default functions return `None`

You should use:

```
int(input("Please enter integer #%d: " % n))
```

Also, if the `input` isn't castable to an `int` this will raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

The `input` function in Python takes a string to print out as an argument.  What you're doing is passing the return value of the `print` function into `input`.  Because `print` doesn't return anything, `input` receives `None` as an argument and prints that out after your string.  Instead, get rid of the call to `print` and just use:

```
def prompt(n):
    value = int(input("Please enter integer # %d : "%n))
    return value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
def prompt(n):
    value= int(input(("Please enter integer #"+ str(n)+ ": ")))
    return value
```