# Beginner python "None" issue

Tags: python

I just started on python and since I started a new calculator project, pyCharm spits out none after everything. I'm not sure what's causing this error, I would appreciate it if I could get some help here. (This is just the main function that I'm showing) Here's the code:

```
def main():
    run = True
    while run == True:
        if run == False:
        break
    try:
        operation = input(print("Would you like to *, -, + or /?"))

        if operation != "+" and operation != "-" and operation != "/" and operation != "*":
            print("invalid input.")
            go = input(print("Would you like to continue, yes or no?"))

        if go == "no":
            run = False

        else:
            continue

        else:
            num1 = int(input(print("What's your first number?")))

            num2 = int(input(print("What's your second number?")))

         if operation == "*":
            print(multi(num1, num2))

         if operation == "-":
            print(sub(num1, num2))

         if operation == "+":
               print(add(num1, num2))

         if operation == "/":
               print(div(num1, num2))

         go = input(print("Would you like to make another calculation, yes or no?"))
         if go == "no":
                run = False
                else:
                    continue

        except:
            print("invalid input.")
            go = input(print("Would you like to continue, yes or no?"))
            if go == "no":
                run = False
            else:
               continue
```

An example of what happens:

```
Would you like to *, -, + or /?
None/
What's your first number?
None3
What's your second number?
None4
0.75
Would you like to make another calculation, yes or no?
Noneno

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in lines 2-4. It is wrong. Also, if run==True in the loop header, it cannot be False on the next line.

Comment: def multi(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2


def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2


def sub(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2


def div(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2

Comment: The `print` functions in your `input` statements return `None`, and that's why you see `None` before the user input.  Remove the calls to `print()`, `input ` will print the text anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [print statement inside of input returns with a "none"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350509/print-statement-inside-of-input-returns-with-a-none)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function signature for input is `input([prompt])`. The brackets indicate that a prompt is optional but basically `input` is expecting you to give a string to print out. Instead, you are giving it a `print()` statement. The return value of a print statement is `None` so that's getting outputted as the prompt by the input statement.

Note, it is also bad practice to have an `except` statement without specifying an error type. Without specifying a type, the `except` will trigger for any error (for example, it triggered when I tried running your code before adding in your functions like `multi`). I think you want `except ValueError` here.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `print` statements from `input` calls:

`input(print("What's your first number?"))` -> `input("What's your first number?\n")` or `input("Your first number: ")`

That `None` is the return value of `print` function that is displayed by `input` function.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the print statement in the input.
Instead of `input(print("Would you like to continue, yes or no?"))`
, Try 
 `input("Would you like to continue, yes or no?")`

That is what i do