# Function prints None when i call it using dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I made a dictionary switcher as follows:

```
switcher={
    0:linked_list,
    1:queue,
    2:stack
    }
```

and I used  `switcher[key]()` to just call a function.
The function runs as normal but the issue is it prints None before 
taking input in while loop of my called function, in this case `linked_list()`

```
while(c!=2):
      c=int(input(print("Enter operation\n1.Insert beg\n2.Exit")))
      if c==1:
          some code
```

I have tried using a `return` statement and `lambda` but still it prints None.Also I am not printing the given function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [print statement inside of input returns with a "none"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350509/print-statement-inside-of-input-returns-with-a-none)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because what you are trying to write to the standard output is not your menu seen as a string but the object resulting from the **print** function.

**print** function is useless. Argument sent to **input** function is by default written to the standard output.

Therefore:

```
while(c!=2):
      c=int(input("Enter operation\n1.Insert beg\n2.Exit\n"))
      if c == 1:
          some code
```

is enough (with an extra newline after Exit option for more readibility).

[See here official documentation about input function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

Comment: Didnt notice the print statment                         Such a dumb mistake, thanks !