# I am a beginner and tried to make a code such that it appears letter by and letter and also accepts an input, but None appears

Tags: python, input, printing, delay

```py
import sys
import time

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.01)

Colour = input(delay_print("Choose a colour(Red/Black):"))
```

Expected_result:

`Choose a colour(Red/Black):`

Actual_result

`Choose a colour(Red/Black):None`

Comment: `input` prints the prompt you supply, in this case your function has no explicit return so implicitly returns None. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/24350509/3001761.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide the `return` value (`None`) from `delay_print()` as the parameter for `input()`. Just split it into two lines:

```py
delay_print("Choose a colour(Red/Black):")
colour = input()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you arrange for delay_print to return an empty string then this will do what you need:

```
from time import sleep

def delay_prompt(s):
    for c in s:
        print(c, end='', flush=True)
        sleep(0.25)
    return ''

value = input(delay_prompt('Hello world: '))
```