# Input statement is resulting with None

Tags: python

I'm trying to call a function within a function that asks for some input. It runs and gives me the right answer, but not before showing "None".

```
def func1(f_temp):
    c_temp = round(float((f_temp - 32) * 5 / 9),1)
    print(f_temp, "degrees Fahrenheit is equal to", c_temp, "degrees Celsius.")

def func2(mph):
    mps = mph * 0.44704
    print(mph, "miles per hour is equal to", mps, "meters per second.")

def main():
    print("Enter 1 to convert Fahrenheit temperature to Celsius.")
    print("Enter 2 to convert speed from miles per hour to meters per second.")
    main_input = int(input())
    if main_input == 1:
        f_temp = input(print("Please enter a temperature in Fahrenheit: "))
        return func1(f_temp)
    elif main_input == 2:
        mph = input(print("Please enter a speed in miles per hour: "))
        return func2(mph)
    else:
        print("Please enter 1 or 2 only.")
```

And here is what happens when I run it:

```
main()
Enter 1 to convert Fahrenheit temperature to Celsius.
Enter 2 to convert speed from miles per hour to meters per second.
1
Please enter a temperature in Fahrenheit: 
None52
52.0 degrees Fahrenheit is equal to 11.1 degrees Celsius.
```

Comment: Change `input(print(...))` to just `input(...)`.  `print` returns `None`.  `input` will print its argument.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/24350509/3001761

Comment: I tried taking out 'print' but now i'm getting "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input()` function receive a string and print it, the `print()` function print a string in the terminal but returns nothing (`None`),

```py
f_temp = input(print("Please enter a temperature in Fahrenheit: "))
```

you are calling `print` inside `input`, so input waits for a string and only gets a `None` and print it, this is why your program writes None in some point. You can fix it :

```py
f_temp = input("Please enter a temperature in Fahrenheit: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change input(print(...)) to just input(...). Print returns None and input() is printing it. (as what @Mark Tolonen said)

```py
def func1(f_temp):
    c_temp = round(float((f_temp - 32) * 5 / 9),1)
    print(f_temp, "degrees Fahrenheit is equal to", c_temp, "degrees Celsius.")

def func2(mph):
    mps = mph * 0.44704
    print(mph, "miles per hour is equal to", mps, "meters per second.")

def main():
    print("Enter 1 to convert Fahrenheit temperature to Celsius.")
    print("Enter 2 to convert speed from miles per hour to meters per second.")
    main_input = int(input())
    if main_input == 1:
        print("Please enter a temperature in Fahrenheit: ", end="")
        f_temp = input()
        return func1(f_temp)
    elif main_input == 2:
        print("Please enter a speed in miles per hour: ", end="")
        mph = input()
        return func2(mph)
    else:
        print("Please enter 1 or 2 only.")
```